# Delphi - How to make a TEdit label the TWebBrowser curently url

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I'm creating a webbrowser and I use a TWebBrowser and a TEdit to type in the url.But when I open a web page with a link then when I click that link, I goes to an another web page and my question is how to make the TEdit label the currently url.

Comment: Are you sure you are using XE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a handler for the `OnNavigateComplete2` event:

```
procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1NavigateComplete2(ASender: TObject;
  const pDisp: IDispatch; const URL: OleVariant);
begin
  Edit1.Text := URL;
end;
```

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/SHDocVw.TWebBrowser.OnNavigateComplete2) says:

> Write an OnNavigateComplete2 event handler to take specific action
>   when the Web browser successfully navigates to a new resource. The
>   event can occur before the document is fully downloaded, but when it
>   occurs at least part of the document must be received and a viewer for
>   the document created.
>
> Note: Unlike the OnDownloadComplete event, OnNavigateComplete2 does not occur if the operation is not successful.

A test with a nonexistent URL revealed that it fires anyway.

You may also want to consider writing a handler for the `OnBeforeNavigate2` event, in case you want to, f.ex. programmatically cancel navigation to a URL

```
procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1BeforeNavigate2(ASender: TObject;
  const pDisp: IDispatch; const URL, Flags, TargetFrameName, PostData,
  Headers: OleVariant; var Cancel: WordBool);
begin
  Edit1.Text := URL;
end;
```